# Computed Property getter in protocol called more times than required

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I have created a private variable in a protocol extension and using that to get an instance of an object.

Even if I call that once, the getter is called twice. I have prepared a Playground to show that.

Below is the code:

```
class LoggingService {
    func sayWorld() {
        print("world")
    }
}

protocol LoggerType {
    func sayWorld()
}

extension LoggerType {
    private var loggerInstance: LoggingService {
        print("init")
        return LoggingService()
    }

    func sayWorld() {
        self.loggerInstance.sayWorld()
    }
}

class ViewMock: LoggerType {
    init() {

    }
}

let viewObj = ViewMock()
viewObj.sayWorld()
```

Have a look at the running playground

[image]

Need some explanation into this behaviour.

Comment: Step one in debugging weird Swift behaviour in a playground is not using a playground. In a compiled project, the getter is only accessed once as expected.

Comment: @Hamish thanks for the response. That was indeed the case. I do not know why Apple does such things.

Comment: If I had to guess I would say it's because the playground is executing `loggedInstance` an additional time in order to display its description in the sidebar on the right.  You can change it to `_ = self.loggerInstance.sayWorld()` so that the sidebar displays the void result of the expression instead and you'll see that it only gets called once.

Comment: @dan you are right. thanks for the answer. Please add your answer so that I can accept and close the question

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @Hamish in comments, in a compiled project this works as expected, i.e., this is called only one time.

I would still like to know why this happens in a Playground. So if anyone has anything to share, I would like to hear.